# Batch Processing Design Patterns

Tags: batch-file, batch-processing

A partner who cannot support a real-time web service interface must SFTP CSV files to my linux environment.

The file is zipped and encrypted. The sftp server is a different virtual server than the one that will process the CSV data into my application's database.

I don't need help with the technical steps (bash script, etc) but I'm looking for file management conventions that assist with the following requirements:

- Good auditabilty
- Non-destructive
- Recoverable

Basically I'm trying to figure out when it makes sense to make copies of the file, when to rename it to indicate some process step has been completed to a file, etc. (e.g. Do I keep the zip files or do I delete them once unzipped?)

There is going to be personal preference in the response, but I'm looking for that; to learn from someone who has more experience working with this type of interface. This seems better than me inventing something myself.

Answer (score 0):

If the files are encrytped upon the network and within the files settings, then it cannot be successfully transmitted across unless the file is parsed within another file. You could try to make the sftp server foward the file onto a seperate machine,but this would only cause more issues because of the encryption type based on the files.